# Strange behavior of System.Random class

Tags: c#, random

```
Random rand = new Random(10);
Console.WriteLine(rand.Next(100));
```

These couple of lines of code *always* gives 95 as the output. And when I make the parameter value of the constructor in the first line "8", then the code always gives 90 as the output. Can anybody point to me why it behaves like this ?

P.S: I'm guessing it's something to do with what the parameter value does to the object of the `Random` class, but a concrete insight into the behavior would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you use the same seed you get the same numbers. If you use the default constructor you get different values because its seeded with the current time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating `Random` instance with the same seed value. It will return the same results when `Next` is called and that's by design.

> Providing an identical seed value to different `Random` objects causes each instance to produce identical sequences of random numbers.
>
> *from [Random Constructor (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx)*

Use parameterless constructor to get instance seeded with time-based value.

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution ...
>
> *from [Random Constructor ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx)*

Comment: Just let me know if you disagree with the closure. Or I think you'll be able to re-open it.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, at least not of a question you linked. That question is about creating multiple `Random` instances within short period of time (e.g. in a loop). This one is about seeding `Random` with predefined seed.

Comment: Thanks, Marcin. Yeah, it makes sense now. :)